# How can I publish only changed files in azure devops

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

I have a folder in my repository, multiple developers add,modify or delete files.
Now I want only updated files when I publish the pipeline artifact during build process.

How can I achieve this during build process?

Comment: You could use [Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to find the last successful build of this pipeline and its associated commit Id. Then use git to determine the list of changed files between that commit and the current one.